# Human readable file name

Tags: django, imagefield

Whenever I create an [ImageField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ImageField) using a file called `moon.png`, Django, correctly following my configuration settings, puts the file in:

```
campaign/primary-banner/2015/11/25/moon.png
```

or

```
campaign/primary-banner/2015/11/25/moon_RcJ3FuD.png
```

And that is the value of [`imagefield.name`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/files/file/#django.core.files.File.name), which I can show to the user, but is not really user friendly.

I would like to show the name of `ImageField.name`, but in a human readable format. Is it possible to extract the original file name (`moon.png`) from the `ImageField`? The workarounds that I can think of are:

- add an extra field to my model to hold the human readable file name. Extra work, which I would like to avoid: DRY.
- process the `imagefield.name` value to extract the original filename, but this seems too complex (I would need to exactly understand how django is generating the filename in the first place, to make sure I cover corner cases)

Comment: That's not DRY, that's DTRT.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams: which is always the case, isn't it? I mean, DRY <= DTRT

Comment: I apologize for not making myself clear enough, allow me to rephrase it. *Do not depend on implementation details for interface behavior.*

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams: ok, point taken, but not sure I follow you there. The implementation I have is what I have. I can not change it. If django is limited in this sense, and can not provide me with the original (short, human-readable) file name, I have no other solution but to workaround that limitation, with any tricks that are necessary to overcome the framework shortcommings. That, in your words, would be *coding around implementation details*. No idea how I can avoid that **if** django has that limitation (still crossing my fingers).

Comment: let me clarify a bit. You want to get file before django upload it to a directory, replace its original name with custom name and then save file with that custom name ?

Comment: @LaLZaDa: no, that's not what I want to do: the way django is storing the files is perfectly fine (partition files by date and what not, to avoid overflowing directory). But at the same time I also need the original, user friendly name (the name by which the user will recognize the file). Django has this just before saving the file, but I would say that this information is just thrown away as soon as the file is stored to disk.

Comment: maybe "slug remove" would be the right keywords for this?

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem and solved it by creating my own subdirectry under MEDIA_ROOT, in which I made directory structure involvind the date and also some unique identifier. Then I moved my file to that final subdirectory and put the name to FileField.name. Everything works like charm - files are unique (thanks to unique directories) and the final name is exactly what i want user to see (as there is no need to rename it - no conflict is possible)

```
p.filename=get_filename_of_existing_file_to_be_stored()
p.originalfilename=get_how_it_should_be_named()
masterobject=MyNewMaster.objects.get(pk=some_id)
uniq_name=masterobject.make_something_unique()


new_object=MyObject()
new_object.master=masterobject
new_object.some_fields=some_values
daystr=date.today().strftime('%y-%m-%d')
directory='MyDir/%s/%s/%s/'%(daystr,masterobject.id,uniq_name)
if not os.path.exists(os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT,directory)):
    os.makedirs(os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT,directory))
fname=os.path.join(directory,p.originalfilename)
os.rename(p.filename,os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT,fname))
new_object.filename = fname
new_object.save()
```

Now everthing works for me and no conflicts are possible and even Django seems happy with this hack and provides the correct filename and url for everything i tried to do with MyObject :)

Now I ended with path like:

```
MyDir/2015-11-29/12345/child_7/moon.png
```